# Auto download attachment from Outlook 2010 to local or network folder using Inbox Rules

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have this piece of code, it works on one computer Outlook 2010 64bit but does not work on another machine running 32bit. I do not think this has anything to do with 32bit/64 but just want to mention it in-case.

I have tried everything, disable macro, turning Outlook inside out and cannot get this code to work.

Maybe a second eye will find something I am missing:

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Strings.Format(Now(), "mm_dd_yyyy_HH_MM_SS_AMPM")
saveFolder = "C:\Users\Jarvis\Desktop\Test"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "My_Data_" & dateFormat & ".csv"
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What error are you getting on the 32-bit computer?  Does the 32-bit computer have the `saveFolder` path already created?

Comment: Yes, I created the folder, I am not getting any errors or messages, and this is what makes it so difficult. However, the computer is on a network, the 64 is local/personal.

Comment: You can try adding this line at the end of the Sub: `MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & "; " & Err.Source` to see if an error is being thrown.

Comment: I get nothing, how does one even know if a script is running? with or without errors?

Comment: I usually check if something is running with either a `MsgBox "test"` or `Debug.Print "test"` line.  I'm not sure if this will be any help, but it seems to have the [same subject as your question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549122(v=office.14).aspx#OL2010SolutionBitness_VBAMacros)

Comment: Finally I get an error message saying: The Macro in this project are disabled.I have Enabled all Macros not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19555/discussion-between-kevin-pope-and-unaverage-guy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19555/discussion-between-kevin-pope-and-unaverage-guy), it seems the solution was to:

1. Copy EVERYTHING out of your VB macro project, into a text file. Save the textfile to your drive.
2. Close everything, reboot the computer.
3. Go to your C:\Documents and settings<yourusernamehere>\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook folder.
4. Either delete the file VBAProject.otm, or (better and safer) rename to VBAProject.old or some similar name.
5. Open Outlook
6. Reopen the VB Macro editor
7. Paste in the code from your text file.

[[Instructions courtesy of Arcane Code]](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/04/outlook-and-macros-are-disabled-error/)

Comment: Kevin you are the greatest - thank you so much for your time and dedication!!